# jquery animate doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#bg1 {
                height:             159px;
                width:              800px;
                margin-left:        auto;
                margin-right:       auto;
                background-image:   url('images/bg1.jpg');
                background-repeat:  no-repeat;
                background-position:center center;
                position:           relative;
                z-index:            3;
            }
            div#bg2 {
                height:             159px;
                width:              800px;
                margin-left:        auto;
                margin-right:       auto;
                background-image:   url('images/bg2.jpg');
                background-repeat:  no-repeat;
                background-position:center center;
                position:           relative;
                z-index:            2;
                margin-top:         -159px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Animate_2() 
            {
                $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);
                $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
                setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
            }

            function Animate_1() 
            {
                $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
                $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);
                setTimeout(Animate_2, 5000);
            }

            $(function()
            {
                /* Start cycle */
                setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg1"></div>
        <div id="bg2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Animate_1() works fine, but Animate_2() will just display the bg2.jpg without animating the opacity.. This is the same in IE and Firefox..

Why is  this >??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is that opacity is a scale of 0 to 1, not 0 to 100. But here are some slight improvements:

You could simplify the code a lot too as you've just got one image on top of another.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var shown = true;

        function toggleFront() {
            shown = !shown;
            $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: shown*1}, 200);
            window.setTimeout(toggleFront, 1000);
        }

        $(function() {
            /* Start cycle */
            window.setTimeout(toggleFront, 500);
        });
    </script>
```

I've messed with your timing values to show it faster.

Or fix it. You need `window.` before setTimeout. Simple fix.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Animate_2() 
        {
            $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
            $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
            window.setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
        }

        function Animate_1() 
        {
            $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
            $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
            window.setTimeout(Animate_2, 5000);
        }

        $(function()
        {
            /* Start cycle */
            window.setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Exactly the same result.. First animate is fine, second time it will not animate but just quickly change the image.

Comment: I see what you mean. Opacity is a scale of 0 to 1, not 0 to 100. It was animating it but it was completely opaque 1 1/100th of the way through. I've fixed both my code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the same results that you describe on Firefox 3.0.10 Ubuntu, `Animate_2` seems to work fine.  At first I thought it might be because you might be using a local file instead of running your page through a localhost server (like apache) but that didn't change the results for me, but I remember problems with that working on the Windows platform in the past.  I also tried it with the following preload script, and that does seem to remove an initial animation stutter on my machine:

```
jQuery.preloadImages = function()
                {
                  for(var i = 0; i").attr("src", arguments[i]);
                    }
                }
$.preloadImages("imgages/bg1.jpg", "imgages/bg2.jpg");
```